# Como contar os valores do tipo NULL no MySql

Tags: mysql, count, sqlfiddle

Tenho uma tabela simples com as respostas, nessa tabela posso ter respostas com valor `null, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...` , só que quando vou contar a quantidade de respostas com cada valor esses com o valor `null` não conta, traz com quantidade zerado.

Segue um exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78441/2) mas segue os dados, query e resultado obtido aqui também.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `respostas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_select` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;


INSERT INTO `respostas` (`id`, `option_select`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, NULL),
(3, 2),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 3),
(7, NULL),
(8, 1),
(9, 0),
(10, 0),
(11, 1);
```

A query que usei para obter a quantidade por opção selecionada é

```
SELECT option_select
FROM  `respostas` 
GROUP BY option_select
```

e o resultado obtido é o seguinte:

```
| option_select | qtde |
|---------------|------|
| null          | 0    |
| 0             | 2    |
| 1             | 4    |
| 2             | 2    |
| 3             | 1    |
```

enquanto o esperado seria o `null` ter qtde de **2**

Comment: O problema é que NULL é um valor que você não tem ideia do que é e, portanto, não pode saber se ele é igual ou diferente de outro NULL. O resultado de qualquer operação envolvendo NULL tem como resultado NULL. Você pode utilizar: campo IS NULL ou campo IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema, podemos utilizar a função [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) que retorna um valor numérico ou string, dependendo do contexto no qual é usado:

mysql> `SELECT IFNULL(1,0);`

```
-> 1
```

mysql> `SELECT IFNULL(NULL,10);`

```
-> 10
```

mysql> `SELECT IFNULL(1/0,10);`

```
-> 10
```

mysql> `SELECT IFNULL(1/0,'yes');`

```
-> 'yes'
```

---

Então aplicando ao seu problema, podemos fazer assim:

```
SELECT option_select, count(IFNULL(option_select,0))
  FROM  `respostas` 
 GROUP BY option_selec
```

e o resultado obtido:

```
| option_select | qtde |
|---------------|------|
|        (null) |    2 |
|             0 |    2 |
|             1 |    4 |
|             2 |    2 |
|             3 |    1 |
```

Pode testar pelo [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0edd4/9) se atende sua necessidade.

Comment: Por acaso saber se isso é algum bug do mysql, se acontece com outros bancos tbm, tipo sql server, mariaDB, oracle, e essa função IFNULL() não conhecia, vivendo e sempre aprendendo. Valew

Comment: Para responder sua pergunta parti do principio do `NVL` do Oracle, do qual estou acostumado, pesquisei e encontrei essa função para MySQL, acredito que se baseiam da função `coalesce` do SQL ANSI, pesquise sobre coalesce em SQL Server, ou até mesmo mariaDB que ira encontrar o que procura.